# Store location and redirect with Facebook API login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've watched [this video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) and I made the authentication correctly.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
   user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
   session[:user_id] = user.id
   redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
   session[:user_id] = nil
   redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

How can I redirect a user to the location he was on previously? Not root_url. What should be in SessionsHelper? I've also looked at [Hartl's tutorial sample code](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb), but I'm using FB API.

Answer (score 0):

You may `redirect_to :back` in your controller or you can use `devise` gem for authentication with `gem 'omniauth-facebook'`. It work as you wish out of the box. See [wiki page at devise git](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview) for implementation